# Generic function that accepts both Actions and Func's as parameters

Tags: c#, error-handling, generics, http

I've created a generic try catch I can apply throughout my code so I'm not repeating myself.

```
private HttpResponseMessage TryCatch(Action action)
{
    return TryCatch(() => { action(); return "ActionToFunc"; });
}

private HttpResponseMessage TryCatch<T>(Func<T> func)
{
    try
    {
        var result = func();

        if (result.ToString() == "ActionToFunc")
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
    }
    catch (ArgumentNullException)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
    }
}
```

I can call it using:

```
TryCatch(() => myFunction(parameter));
```

Is there a better way of doing achieving the same result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to avoid using magic values. This one is a hack to avoid writing 2 methods.

> ```
> private HttpResponseMessage TryCatch(Action action)
> {
>     return TryCatch(() => { action(); return "ActionToFunc"; });
> }
> ```

You are better of splitting your methods. Dispatch error handling to its own method `ResolveStatusCode` to avoid boiler-plate error handling. In addition, perform argument checks. Since your method is `private`, I would favor `Debug.Assert` over `ArgumentNullException`.

```
    HttpResponseMessage TryCatch(Action operation)
    {
        try
        {
            Debug.Assert(operation != null, "invalid usage of API");
            operation();
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(ResolveStatusCode(error));
        }
    }

    HttpResponseMessage TryCatch<T>(Func<T> func)
    {
        try
        {
            Debug.Assert(func != null, "invalid usage of API");
            var result = func();
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(ResolveStatusCode(error));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I think you're right, this is definitely the way to go. Thanks for introducing me to Debug.Assert() as well, it's something I haven't seen before and will be looking into.

Answer (score 2):

I want to start off by saying [dfhwze](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/221440/52662) is the correct answer.

I just wanted to touch more on the magic string "ActionToFunc".  Sometimes, especially with functional programming, you need to convert an Action to a Func<>.  I would copy what is already proven and working by borrowing from F# and Rx and create a Unit struct

Here is documentation on F# about Unit 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/unit-type

and Rx info on Unit 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/reactive-extensions/hh211727(v%3Dvs.103)

Both state Unit Struct Represents void.

And here is the Rx source code for Unit, in case you don't want to add Rx just for a struct.

https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/f71f2d62fcec2eb44ca6eaced3b58b21e0372076/AsyncRx.NET/System.Reactive.Shared/System/Reactive/Unit.cs

*Repeat* this isn't the case for it but for example instead of magic string would have done

```
if (result == Unit.Default) // Treat this as a void method
```